# How to set a focus to an input field in method invoked after onchange() event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got problems with setting focus to an input field after validating it.

I've got two fields: from and to.

```
   <spring:message code="template.fields.label.from"/>: 
       <mvc:input  path="templateFields.selectorRangeFrom" 
       onchange="validateNumber('templateFields.selectorRangeFrom',true)"/>
   <spring:message code="template.fields.label.to"/>: 
      <mvc:input path="templateFields.selectorRangeTo"   
     onchange="validateNumber('templateFields.selectorRangeTo',true)"/>
```

And I've got method `validateNumber()` which validates the field and returns false if the field is invalid, true otherwise.
However the focus never stays on invalid number, it will always go the next object.

```
function validateNumber(index,isInteger) {
 var object = document.getElementById(index);
 var value = object.value;   
 if (testNumeric2(value,isInteger)==false)   {
     alert('Please correct the value: ' + value);               
     object.focus();
     object.select();
     return false;  
 } 
return true;    
 }
```

I have found out that if I add: `event.returnValue=false` (before returning false), then it works for IE.
But I can't find the solution for Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**setTimeout()** allows you to defer the execution of a function for a number of milliseconds - if you use zero, this simply means, "do this as soon as you're done with whatever you're doing now" - handling the event, in your case.

Try this:

```
if (! /** check field **/) {
   /** show error **/
   setTimeout((function() { object.focus() }), 0);
}
```

Basically you would be creating a function that will focus your input box, and then instructing the browser to call it as soon as it's done doing the default handling of the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what returning false for **onChange** is supposed to mean. If you merely wish to re-focus the problem area, I would suggest you do this via a **setTimeout()** call (you will have to create a closure around your input element).

This way the event handling will be complete when you attempt to focus the text box.

As a side note, I would also suggest you don't use **alert()** to notify the user of an error, since it is jarring, and can cause a harsh unexpected sound on many Windows systems. Displaying an icon next to, or a red border around the trouble control would probably be a much better way to treat the user.